# how to Include the buildnumber in maven pdf:pdf

Tags: maven, buildnumber-maven-plugin, maven-pdf-plugin

I am trying to include the build number in the pdf's that get generated with the maven pdf plugin. I have all the documentation of the project I am working on written as a maven site. This way all the documentation is stored with the source code.

#### Pom.xml

So in the pom.xml I have defined the buildnumber plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <phase>generate-resources</phase>
       <goals>
         <goal>create</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <doCheck>false</doCheck>
     <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
     <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}_{1}</format>
     <items>
       <item>timestamp</item>
   <item>${user.name}</item>
     </items>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

#### pdf.xml

And in the pdf.xml

```xml
<cover>
  <coverTitle>${project.name}</coverTitle>
  <coverSubTitle>v. ${project.version}</coverSubTitle>
  <coverType>Technical documentation</coverType>
  <coverVersion>build: ${project.buildNumber}</coverVersion>
  <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
  <projectLogo>images/telfortlogo.jpg</projectLogo>
 </cover>
```

I even put resource filtering to `${basedir}/site` but it has no effect. I keep getting the ${buildNumber} instead of the result of the buildnumber plugin.

Comment: you may simply need to add "buildNumber" into the items section? since you added some there the default might got lost.

Comment: I think the property is `${buildNumber}`.  The config shown has `${project.buildNumber}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get something similar working my buildnumber plugin configuration looked like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>pre-site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <format>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}_{1}</format>
                <items>
                    <item>timestamp</item>
                    <item>${user.name}</item>
                </items>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And in the pdf.xml:

```xml
<cover>
    <coverTitle>${project.name}</coverTitle>
    <coverSubTitle>v. ${project.version} build ${buildNumber}</coverSubTitle>
    <coverType>User Guide</coverType>
    <projectName>${project.name}</projectName>
</cover>
```

I believe that your issue comes from the fact that you are executing the buildnumber create goal during the generate-resources phase. And if you are using `mvn pdf:pdf` or `mvn site`, the generate-resources will not get executed.
I my setup I have configured the pdf plugin to run on the site phase:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pdf-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pdf</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>pdf</goal>
            </goals>
```

I can then get the pdf to be generated at the end of the site phase.